# Set volume to 100% on start up - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, startup

I am running chrome in kiosk mode on Ubuntu 12.04 with headphones in.

When i reboot the volume is setting itself to 50% is there a script i could run maybe in startup applications that sets to volume to 100%. Or someway of always forcing it to be 100% volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add any of this command in your startup script (like **/etc/rc.local**)

**/usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume 0 100%**

or

**/usr/bin/amixer -D pulse sset Master 100%**